# how to prevent multicast packets from being snooped

Tags: network, sniffer, snooping

As we know, any user can send IGMP to join a multicast group, which means an unauthirized user can capture any multicast packets in a traditional LAN.

I want to prevent the multicast packets from being snooped by unauthorized user, is there any technology for this?

I know IGMP snooping is a mechanism to analyze IGMP protocols at layer 2, but I am not sure if IGMP snooping can be set to forward the multicast packets only to the authorized LAN switch ports.

thank you in advance

cheng

Answer (score 2):

> I want to prevent the multicast packets from being snooped by unauthorized user,

Since there is no **authorization** in multicast you cannot prevent snooping by an **unauthorized** user. What you can do instead is to encrypt the multicast traffic and distribute the decryption keys only to the users which should be able to access the content.